# Geogebra graphing help

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, math-software

I'm trying to draw a wave in geogebra, something like the one on a pepsi logo. The wave is a vertical wave and I have no idea how to draw it.

I tried drawing a sine graph but I want a 'single' wave, which is 'vertical'

Any ideas?

Comment: I sorted out with making a vertical wave now. Thx! But how do I have a 'single' wave?

Comment: Geogebra or algebraic geometry ;)

Answer (score 1):

- To reduce the “multiple” sine wave to a “single” one, multiply with a boolean value such as $x^2<\pi^2$, for instance. Just type `sin(x) (x^2 < pi^2)` into the input bar, and then hit enter.
- To transform a horizontal wave into a vertical one, use `Rotate[...]`.

Answer (score 0):

A vertical wave is not a function of $x$. You might try $x = \cos y$, which is just a normal wave, except vertically.

Comment: Technically true and mathematically correct, but *GeoGebra* does not accept as input explicit functions of argument other than *x*, and implicit equations are only accepted if they are polynomial in *x* and/or *y*.

Answer (score 0):

You can just reflect $\sin(x)$ in the line $y=x$ thus:

[web.geogebra.org/?command=Reflect[sin(x),y=x]](http://web.geogebra.org/?command=Reflect[sin(x),y=x])